# magic with z-index

Tags: css

Okay, I have typical menu (`ul>li>a`). The mission is to draw background `<div>` (shadow, gradient etc) into an `<li>` element (`ul>li>.shadow-bg-white`)
(for example, the div is green bordered. all other borders are just for better visibility of problem)

http://jsfiddle.net/voilalal/P57yE/embedded/result/ or http://jsfiddle.net/voilalal/P57yE/6/
(for example, the div is bordered with green color)

If I hover over the items from left to right, everything is okay. However, if I hover over the items from right to left, items on the left side do not react to the `:hover` pseudo-class.

Every block has the CSS `position` property assigned, so `z-index` should work well, I hope.

At least, `.shadow-bg-white` `z-index` seems to be placed higher than the `a` item.

What solution can you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benjam was on the general right track I think. I don't know your ultimate purpose, so the solution may not work in your case, but there is no other solution. The `li` you are hovering on must be set lower than the others so the `div` in it does not overlap them. Adding this:

```
#header-menu ul li:hover {
    z-index: 498; /* one lower than your set z-index for li */
}
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/P57yE/8/.

The reason it worked going left is that by default when items are at the same `z-index` the one coming later in the source order is given precedence, so as you move right you move down in your html source order and the hover is picked up on the new element with the same `z-index`. But when you move left, you are going up in the html source order so the one you were hovering on had precedence and the hover remains.

Comment: Well said, and an elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

They don't react because they are being covered by the div, therefore the div is stealing the hover from anything below it.

If the div does not need to be covering all of the LIs, you might want to place it below the LIs with z-index.  But I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, so I'm not sure if that solution will work for you.